# Chrome 46+ z-Index issue with child items. Maybe related to keyframe animation

Tags: google-chrome, z-index, keyframe

Its seems as though Chrome made a change recently in the latest release of their browser that seems to change the way it is treating a z-indexed child item.

I have created the following jsbin which illustrates the issue.

http://jsbin.com/sotunaqoza/edit?html,css,js,console,output

If you click the block, it will animate and show the back of the block (from Red to Green). Problem is, if you click the text in the green block, then it says the first frame(Red) is clicked. i.e. its child elements are not respecting the z-index order. If you click on the box but outside the text area, then it correctly determines the click to be coming from the upper most layer (green).

This works as expected in both Firefox and IE. This used to work fine in chrome a few versions ago.

A new chrome bug? Something recently introduced? Maybe I am just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report, Chrome team is investigating.  Follow [bug 565089](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565089) for progress.